# Return chart height after zooming the worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I tried `PlotArea.InsideHeight` in a similar way to the example in its [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/api/excel.plotarea.insideheight) to draw a Shape with an equal size next to the plot.

However, if the window zoom has changed recently (regardless of the particular value), this property holds a wrong value. Re-running the code gets the correct value.

Minimal reproducing example, assuming that `chart_object` exists,

```vb
Dim i
For Each i in Array(100, 85, 100, 115, 100)
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = i
    msgbox chart_object.Chart.PlotArea.InsideHeight
Next
```

This shows `PlotArea.InsideHeight` is unreliable.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, for me the value is always the same

Comment: Maybe there's something special about my chart, then... Anyway, this means the current wording of my question must be incorrect. Thanks for checking!

Comment: Not reproducible here either. Things like this used to be a problem in older versions of Excel, like 2003 and earlier, and maybe in 2007, which was really flaky. But I haven't had issues with these things in ages.

Comment: I consistently see the problem even in up-to-date Excel, but with charts originally created in 2003. Shall I close the question then?

Answer (score 1):

The issue proved difficult to trace.
Still, let me leave a piece of advice for a possible future reader:
adding a newly-drawn Shape to `chart_object.Chart.Shapes` rather than to `ActiveSheet.Shapes` allows to specify the position of the Shape within the local coordinate system of the chart (so one shouldn't add `chart_object.Chart.Top` to get global coordinates). This produces a Shape of more robust size and position, which, hopefully, won't pop back and forth when zooming the window.